# Direction of ray passing through the center of thin lens

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

[image]

In my textbook this rule is given. Is there a proof for this? (Paraxial symmetry can be assumed I think)

Comment: Wait so the optical center is not defined to be at the center? But if it is at the center, and there is a ray coming with an angle, how does it not get deflected?

Comment: If the lens is thin enough then to a reasonable approximation a ray does go through the "centre" of the lens and the lateral displacement of the ray is small enough to ignore.  So there is no proof other than making the approximation that I have just described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a perfect lens, a cylinder of rays or a cone of rays that spread out from a point are perfectly focused to a point.

In the early stages of lens design, perfect lenses are assumed. This allows a rough design to be set up - How many lenses and roughly where they are. As the design progresses, imperfection need to be considered. Shapes, positions, and glass type are refined to reduce imperfections as much as possible.

Paraxial rays are rays parallel and close to the optical axis. This is used in early stages. Parameters such as focal length are measured with paraxial rays.

Rays that hit the lens farther from the axis may find a different focal length. This is one of the most common lens imperfections. It is called spherical aberration. The shape of a perfect lens is not a sphere. But until recently, a sphere was the only shape it was possible to make accurate to a wavelength of light or so. Spherical aberration is small near the axis, and grows as you get farther away.

Consider you diagram with a window instead of a lens. The ray would bend as it entered the window, and bend back to its original angle as it left. It would be deflected sideways a small amount, but the angle would not be deviated. If the window was thin, the deflection would be small.

In the early stages of lens design, a lens is approximated as thin. This means deflection from the thickness is ignored. Near the axis, a lens looks a lot like a window. If you approximate it as thin, you get a ray that passes straight through without deflection.

In later stages, you would trace exactly where the ray goes. You might also consider diffraction effects.

For many problems, you don't need to do a full lens design. You might just buy an achromat or a triplet lens. These are two or three element lenses that have already had the aberrations minimized. You treat the lens as perfect and are pretty close to correct.

Or you might have a simple problem where a singlet lens is good enough. Reading glasses or a magnifying glass are examples. You can see that it behaves differently near the edge. But you use the center and that is good enough.

Comment: Great explanation!

Comment: So the deviation is minimized at the center of the lens? Is this because the gradient of the normal vector is the smallest near the center, so any deviation would lead to a miniscule deviation in angle? What does that have to do with spherical abberation?

Comment: The surface on both sides is vertical at the center of the lens. The surfaces are parallel. This is why it is like a window. Higher up, the surfaces are not parallel. This part of the lens is like a prism. A prism changes the ray's direction. You could arrange whole lot of prisms to direct incoming light toward a single point. This is what a lens does.

Comment: Ahh, yeah... that was a brainfart. Thank you for your good response!

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the lease surfaces through which the ray passes are parallel to each other. Hence for this ray the lens acts like a planparallel plate, such as a window pane. This is of course only approximately true, if the lens is thin enough.

Answer (score 0):

Lens is constructed from two spherical surfaces. Ray, which is passing along the optical centre, goes along the normal to the sphere (it is geometrical fact), hence its angle of incidence is zero and hence refracted ray goes also with zero angle. Same thing happens when the ray goes out from the sphere.

Comment: But the angle of incidence is not 0. The ray is coming in with an angle...

Comment: The angle of incidence is by definition the angle between the incident ray and the normal to the surface. The ray is coming with an angle - so does the normal to the surface; as these angles are equal, the angle of incidence is zero.